# Replacing XAML binding based on visual state in Windows 8

Tags: xaml, binding, windows-8, windows-runtime

I use the VisualStateManager-Element to re-locate some XAML-elements on my page based on the current Visual State.
My problem is that I use a gridview which has to become a listview when the window is snapped (because of the small horizontal space left). I bound some other elements to the gridview's selectedItem property. My first approach was to create a listview and show/hide it based on the visual state. I would need to update the binding of my other elements as well though ( from gridView.selectedItem to listView.selectedItem) which is apparently impossible in the visualstatemanager. Another possibility would be to change the binding from code behind.
Are there other solutions (preferably in XAML)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the generally accepted answer would be that you should have a piece of xaml per visual state.  You collapse the one that is not currently in use.  You would only make changes or create bindings manually if you were going to do something that required a dynamic number of bindings or something similar.  In this case you have a fixed set of bindings to a known set of UI elements, so you would simply setup all the bindings in xaml.